# Channeloption.ip-tos-bit not set properly in syn/ack packet in the tcp handshake

Tags: netty

I have set the iptos bit to the right value during the netty server initialisation. But when I capture the packets and check, I see that the SYN/ACK packet goes with the default IPTOS value whereas the following data packets go with the right value that I have set. Is there an api in netty  to set the iptos bit before the channel bind call?

Code snippet :

```
ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
            bootstrap.group(boss,worker)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                            socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new EchoServerHandler());
                            socketChannel.config().setOption(ChannelOption.IP_TOS, 0xC0);
                        }
```

Also i tried setting the channel option configuration on the serverbootstrap since the parameters that we set using ServerBootStrap.option apply to the ChannelConfig of a newly created ServerChannel, i.e., the server socket which listens for and accepts the client connections. These options will be set on the Server Channel when bind() or connect() method is called. This channel is one per server.
Code snippet :bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.IP_TOS, 192);

But i got this below warning during the server startup :
| io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap | Unknown channel option 'IP_TOS' for channel

Comment: Please show the code snipped that shows how you set the option

Comment: Please show the full code snipped... Like do you do this in a `ChannelInitializer` ? Please also show the bootstrap code.

Comment: @NormanMaurer : Can you please have a look into this issue ? i have updated with all the details .